# Warning: Illegal offset type but in_array() returns true PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am receiving `Warning: Illegal offset type in...` with the following code:

```
$this->open_nodes[$new_node]
```

In this case `$new_node`is a custom object but I have implemented the `__toString()` method for it.

Now I would usually just assume that the element is not in the array, but calling `in_array($new_node, $this->open_nodes)` is returning true when called the line directly before.

I also have the same code running in a separate module with only slight differences to the node class and it is running fine.

Comment: `in_array` checks for values, your using it as index. That is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> Arrays and objects can not be used as keys. Doing so will result in a warning: Illegal offset type.

If you want the `__toString()` to take effect you need to cast it:

`$this->open_nodes[(string) $new_node]`

Also `in_array()` is checking that `$new_node` is in the `values` (NOT `keys`) of `$this->open_nodes`, so there must be some other code that is putting it there.

Answer (score 0):

i think we miss some code here, 
what are you trying to do with the first `$this->open_nodes[$new_node];`? 
The in_array will check if there is an element in an litteral array (`[a, b, n]`) in your case it looks like you are trying to add an element to the position `$new_node`, there is no way it can find it.
What you could do is search in the array keys, using 
`in_array($new_node, array_keys($this->open_nodes))`

Answer (score 0):

With the warning

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in...
```

You need to specify a key and assign a node to it.

```
$this->open_nodes['node_name'] = $node;
```

I think you need to look at the function [array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)
I made an example of what your code I thinks looks like

```
class Example
{
  protected $open_nodes = [];
  
  public function __construct($open_nodes = [])
  {
    $this->open_nodes = $open_nodes;
  }
  
  public function check_exists($key)
  {
    return array_key_exists($key, $this->open_nodes);
  }
}

$example = new Example([
  'node_one' => 'Node one test',
  'node_two' => 'Node two test',
]);

if((bool)$example->check_exists('node_one'))
{
  echo "Node one exists" . PHP_EOL;
} else {
  echo "Node one doesn't exist" . PHP_EOL;
}

if((bool)$example->check_exists('node_three'))
{
  echo "Node three exists";
} else {
  echo "Node three doesn't exist";
}
```